# 同じubuntuなのに実行エラー

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

インテルのNUC上で開発したC++のプログラムをマウスコンピューターに移植しました。
ビルドはうまくいったのに、実行時にエラーになりました。
そのときのエラーメッセージは次の通りです。

> boost::math::detail::erf_inv_initializer
>   boost::math::policies::policy,
>   boost::math::policies::promote_double,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy> >::init::do_init()
>   0x00007f09690de025_GLOBAL__sub_I_sac.cpp 0x00007f096905f1d9
>   0x00007f09745104ea 0x00007f09745105fb
>   0x00007f0974500cfa 0x0000000000000008
>   0x00007ffdf89831c7 0x00007ffdf8983213
>   0x00007ffdf898321a 0x00007ffdf8983227
>   0x00007ffdf8983231 0x00007ffdf8983248
>   0x00007ffdf8983253 0x00007ffdf898326b
>   0x0000000000000000

エラーメッセージを見る限り、boostのmathライブラリからの問題のようです。
同じOSの環境なのに、こんなことってあるんでしょうか。
あるとしたらどうすればよろしいでしょうか。

追加情報です。
次のエラーも見つかりました。

> policies::promote_float,
>   boost::math::policies::promote_double,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy,
>   boost::math::policies::default_policy> >::init::do_init() () from
>   /usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so.1.8

これを見る限り、倍精度がつかえないということでしょうか。

同じソースコードを別のコンピュータに持って来て再ビルドしました。
環境はubuntu:16.04,boost:105800,CXX:GNU5.4.0です。そのほかとしては、NUCは4コア、マウスコンピュータは2コアです。

マウスコンピュータの方、インタラクティブに実行すると、必ず「Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)」（不正な命令）で終了します。恐らく、ライブラリが合わないのか、スペックが足りないのでしょうか。

ちなみに、マウスコンピュータのcpuは、Celeron Dual-Core 3865U(Kaby Lake)です。-mtuneコンパイルオプションで設定するには、どのように入力したらよろしいでしょうか。

コンパイルオプションとして、「-march=native」としてもダメでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ubuntu や boost、C++コンパイラのバージョン情報を追記をお願いいたします。また一点確認させて頂きたいのですが、別のコンピュータに移植したというのは、同じソースコードを別のコンピュータに持ってきて再ビルドした、ということでしょうか？

Comment: そのとおり、同じソースコードを別のコンピュータに持って来て再ビルドしました。ubuntu:16.04,boost:105800,CXX:GNU5.4.0です。そのほかとしては、NUCは4コア、マウスコンピュータは2コアです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 共有ライブラリ `/usr/local/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so.1.8` もビルドしてインストールしたのでしょうか？

Comment: マウスコンピュータの方、インタラクティブに実行すると、必ず「Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)」（不正な命令）で終了します。恐らく、ライブラリが合わないのか、スペックが足りないのかだと思われます。

Comment: コンパイルの際に `-mtune=` オプション等で比較的新しい CPU でのみ実行できる AVX 命令を使うように指示していたりしませんか？　コンパイルオプションを提示してみるとか、変更してみるとかしてください。

Comment: それぞれの環境でビルドしたのであれば、ビルド時のログファイル等に差分が無いか確認してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。ちなみに、-mtune= オプションがよくわからないのですが、どのように設定すればよろしいでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ちなみに、マウスコンピュータのcpuは、Celeron Dual-Core 3865U(Kaby Lake)です。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 3865U は AVX 非対応のようなので `-mtune=` なり `-mcpu=` なりを不適切に指定すると動かなくなるはずです。というわけで `Makefile` の中のコンパイルオプション文字列を探して訂正するに１票。

Comment: 正しくネイティブコンパイルしてそれでも動かない、という場合によくあるのはコンパイルしたバイナリファイルを実行していない単純ミスです。あるいは今回コンパイル対象としていないライブラリ `*.a` や `*.so` に異 `-march=` なものが含まれている場合です。どっちにせよネット越しのやりとりでは埒があかない可能性が大です。先入見なしに慎重にデバッグするしかないでしょう。